# include html file in aspx page

Tags: html, asp.net

I have this `<div class='divname'>...</div>` where I use this in many other pages. 
Instead of repeating this code can we create a `html` file and include it in `aspx` page? if yes how?

*I am not using Masterpage, and my backend is vb.net*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An alternative to include plain html in your .aspx files is to use old asp include directive, like this:

```
<!-- #include file="~/path/to/your-static-file.html" -->
```

This way you don't need to create .net controls or masterpage as you said, just include the file you already have.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating separate html file, you can create [User Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you are trying to create separate html you need to specify all the tags for e.g.
`<html><head></head><body></body></html>` etc.

In User Control you can just add your code like `<div class='divname'>...</div>`